# Unable to Redirect after declaring a new Entity ZF2

Tags: redirect, zend-framework2

I been following the codes for the ZF2 website.

The following code used to work.
The output of the website is plain when it did not work.
Other redirect on other controller is working.

Thanks in advance =)

```
public function addAction() {
    $form = new CustomerForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        //$form->setInputFilter($customer->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('customer/sub', array('controller' => 'customer')); //<-- This line works
            $customer = new Customer();
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('customer/sub', array('controller' => 'customer')); //<-- This line does not working

            $customer->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getCustomerTable()->saveCustomer($customer);
            // Redirect to list of albums
            //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('customer/sub', array('controller' => 'customer'));
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Customer.php

```
namespace Customer\Model;

class Customer {
public $customerID;
public $name;
public $code;
public $address;
public $postalCode;
public $country;
public $city;
public $state;
public $contactPersonName;
public $contactEmail;
public $contactTel;
public $contactFax;
public $status;
public $credit;
protected $inputFilter;                       // <-- Add this variable

public function exchangeArray($data) {

    $this->customerID = (isset($data['customerID'])) ? $data['customerID'] : null;

    $this->name = (isset($data['name'])) ? $data['name'] : null;

    $this->code = (isset($data['code'])) ? $data['code'] : null;

    $this->address = (isset($data['address'])) ? $data['address'] : null;

    $this->postalCode = (isset($data['postalCode'])) ? $data['postalCode'] : null;

    $this->country = (isset($data['country'])) ? $data['country'] : null;

    $this->city = (isset($data['city'])) ? $data['city'] : null;

    $this->state = (isset($data['state'])) ? $data['state'] : null;

    $this->contactPersonName = (isset($data['contactPersonName'])) ? $data['contactPersonName'] : null;

    $this->contactEmail = (isset($data['contactEmail'])) ? $data['contactEmail'] : null;

    $this->contactTel = (isset($data['contactTel'])) ? $data['contactTel'] : null;

    $this->contactFax = (isset($data['contactFax'])) ? $data['contactFax'] : null;

    $this->status = (isset($data['status'])) ? $data['status'] : null;

    $this->credit = (isset($data['credit'])) ? $data['credit'] : null;
}

// Add content to this method:



}
?>
```

Comment: it seems that your Customer object is not instantiating try taking Dump of  $customer = new Customer();. if you see errors then i think you need to check your model

Comment: tried dumping, output have no error, showing all the values used in Customer.



object(Customer\Model\Customer)#370 (15) { ["customerID"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["code"]=> NULL ["address"]=> NULL ["postalCode"]=> NULL ["country"]=> NULL ["city"]=> NULL ["state"]=> NULL ["contactPersonName"]=> NULL ["contactEmail"]=> NULL ["contactTel"]=> NULL ["contactFax"]=> NULL ["status"]=> NULL ["credit"]=> NULL ["inputFilter":protected]=> NULL }

Comment: have you taken dump inside IsValid() ?

Comment: yeah I added inside isValid()

Comment: well it looks perfectly alright if it is as you are saying, try clearing cache and then retry

Comment: Tried doing it for a few hours with different browsers and computers, but to no avail. Surprisingly the data is still added into the database. Changing the redirection path doesn't work as well, gets stuck on the same path on the blank page. Any suggestions to bypass the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is dying on your `$customer = new Customer()` call. Do you have a use statement above to inject the Customer/Model?